# problem in importing sqlite to coredata

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-data

I have implemented coredata in my app.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iBountyHunter.sqlite"];
```

This gives me error -[NSURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d394a0'

I tried to find solution, but could not find perfect solution.
How to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sanna is Correct..

Try this code.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iBountyHunter.sqlite"];
```

Comment: This code does not give me error. But data from DB file is not loading.

Answer (score 2):

Your applictionDocumentsDirectory is returning a NSURL not a NSString, so the third line is trying to call stringByAppendingPathComponent on an NSURL-object.